# how to use javascript pass value to php or txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```js
<?php
      $myFile = "new.txt";
    $fileOpen = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "total;
    fwrite($fileOpen, $stringData);
    fclose($fileOpen);
      ?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
         var defaultValue = 5;
         var plus = 1;
         var max = 100;
         var total = defaultValue;
         
     window.setInterval(

     function () {

        
         if (total > max){
         
         total = defaultValue;

         }
        
         document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = total;


                        total = total + plus;

     }, 1000);
         
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I need save the total value into txt file, and than read by txt. so that, when i refresh the browser will not re-looping, but how i get value from javascript or from div into php? (read and write per second)

Comment: Google AJAX POST request.

Comment: It seems cookies would be better suited for this, would they not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to save very small amount of data, like here you need to save the value of total then you can use HTML 5 provided local storage which can easily contain on average 5 MB of data. Its nothing but a storage in each domain(origin) which can store 5 MB on any individual client.
It is very easy to use like.

```
  enter code here

     // Store
    localStorage.totalValueHolder = total;
    // Retrieve
   var totalStringValue = localStorage.totalValueHolder;
    total = parseInt(totalStringValue, 10)
OR
// Store`enter code here`
localStorage.setItem("totalValueHolder ", total);
// Retrieve
var totalStringValue = localStorage.getItem("totalValueHolder");
total = parseInt(totalStringValue, 10)
```

Hope it will answer your question. If you have further query please let us know.

Comment: This is can work, but i want save in the storage permanently, use any browser any computer can do the calculation continuously...
(like a 'Jackpot')
can you give me some example...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an AJAX request to a php file where you can save it to txt file or a database.

But, making an ajax call every second would be unnecessary traffic. Instead I think using `window.onunload` would be a better choice, which saves the value when the page is redirected or refrshed.

**You can use the jquery bind for that as below:**

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  // make ajax call here
});
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar in AJAX, can you give some example? i want to like 'Jackpot'